# Listing the name of the files under some url using java

Tags: java

I want to list every file with extension of ".png" under some url for example

```
"http://kgs:8080/KGS/assets/"
```

I want to retrieve the name of the file such as

```
background.png
foreground.png
```

How can i do this java?

Thank you

Comment: If the `http://kgs:8080/KGS/assets/` returns a list, then you can parse that. Othwise there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP protocol does not have a method for listing files in a directory, so this can't be done in the general case.

If a request made to `http://kgs:8080/KGS/assets/` returns the directory listing in HTML, like some web servers do, you can parse that listing to obtain a list of URLs. Then you go over each URL and check if they end with `.png`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Joni

Answer (score 1):

If the content (the files) is not accessible from the html pages, it is impossible to get it without brute-forcing and guessing the paths. If the files are linked from the html pages, you may want to use some crawler for it.

- For Java there is [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/).